# Dataweave: Create an array of repeated elements

Tags: dataweave

With the following input:

```
{
    name: "Hello",
    numberOfCopies: 10
}
```

I want to generate the following output:

```
[
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello",
  "Hello"
]
```

I found a solution (see the response) but I wonder if is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = {
    name: "Hello",
    numberOfCopies: 10
}
---
(1 to data.numberOfCopies) map data.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something working but I am creating a string to split it in elements:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings

var item = 
{
    name: "Hello",
    numberOfCopies: 10
}
---
{
    names: trim(repeat(item.name++" ",item.numberOfCopies)) splitBy  " "
}.names
```